# NFetchedResultsController delegate method didChangeContentWith is not called when deleted an item using UIDIffableDataSource tableview

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, diffabledatasource, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

I am trying to implement my existing coredata project using the UITableViewDiffableDataSource. My tableview is coupled using the NSFetchedResultsController and the corresponding delegate methods. 
I am able to list the data in the tableview using diffabledatasource. My datasource is declared with the generic types as below

```
UITableViewDiffableDataSource<String, NSManagedObjectID>
```

For enabling the editing mode in the tableview I subclassed the UITableViewDiffableDataSource. I can delete the cell from the tableview but not from my coreData. The code for deleting the cell is as below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .delete {
     if let identifierToDelete = itemIdentifier(for: indexPath){
        var snapshot = self.snapshot()
        snapshot.deleteItems([identifierToDelete])
        apply(snapshot)
     }
  }}
```

The below NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method is not called when I delete the cell.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference)
```

I am not sure whether this is the correct way of coupling diffabledatasource with NSFetchedResultscontroller. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Rather than overriding `tableView(_:commit:)` in `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` implement

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? { ...
```

in the view controller and get the object by the index path from the fetched results controller.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be editing the snapshot, instead edit the model. I.e. delete the managed object as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {  
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;  
        NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [self itemIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath];  
        Event *event = [context objectWithID:objectID];  
        [context deleteObject:event];  
        NSError *error = nil;  
        if (![context save:&error]) {  
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.  
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.  
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);  
            abort();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

After deleting the object the `didChangeContentWith` snapshot object will be called with the new snapshot containing this change which you can apply to your datasource.

Note: You need to add a `managedObjectContext` property to your `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` subclass.